# Android Studio: Mi activitymain.xml no reconoce variables de string.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, string

Tengo una aplicación muy básica en android studio, que accede al acelerómetro y al giroscopio, y sus respectivos valores se muestran en la aplicación.

Todo iba bien hasta que "de repente", no se reconocen los textos de la actividad principal, cuyo contenido están definidos en el fichero string.xml. Por ejemplo:

Tengo mi fichero activity_main.xml con cosas del este estilo:

```
   <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="@string/sens_accelerometer"
        android:background="#e9ff7a81"/>
</TableRow>
```

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/axisX_text"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"/>
</TableRow>....</TableLayout>
```

Por otro lado, el fichero string.xml es del estilo:

```
  <resources>
    <string name="app_name"> Sensors </string>
    .....
    <string name="sens_accelerometer">Accelerometer </string>
    ....
</resources>
```

Iba todo bien hasta hoy, el error que me aperece es el que adjunto en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el error se da en el fichero activity_main.xml, cada vez que quiero acceder a un string de string.xml, es decir, en líneas similares a:

```
 android:text="@string/sens_accelerometer"
```

¿Alguien podría aconsejarme sobre cual podría ser la causa? No fui capaz de solucionarlo.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Hiciste algún cambio en el Manifest? Muestra el XML completo.

Comment: ¿Android Studio te indica que el error es en las líneas donde llamas a los strings? Yo creo que el problema esta en otra línea del activity_main, comparte el código completo de tu layout principal y si la aplicación te indica donde se produce el error indícalo.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta hacer esto desde Android Studio, no parece haber nada malo con tu string

```
Build - Clean project - Rebuild Project
```